# Slow response time when HTML table is large

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, html-table

My HTML table is getting more time to load when the row count is large. I have to load almost 50000 row table to the webpage. I just used basic HTML table. ASP.NET C#.

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Available Resistors In Stock</h3>
                <!--
    <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="task-table-filter" data-action="filter" data-filters="#task-table" placeholder="Filter Resistors" />
-->
            </div>
            <table class="table table-hover" id="task-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="center">#</th>
                        <th class="center">Resistor Type</th>
                        <th class="center">Resistor Value</th>
                        <th class="center">Ohm</th>
                        <th class="center">Location</th>
                        <th class="center">PL</th>
                        <th class="center">Place</th>
                        <th class="center">Category</th>
                        <th class="center">Quantity</th>
                        <th class="center">Part NO</th>
                        <th class="center">Description</th>
                        <th class="center">Active</th>
                        <th class="center">Edit</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        <tr class="center">
                            <td>@Model.Rows[i][0]</td>
                            <td>@Model.Rows[i][1]</td>
                            <td>@Model.Rows[i][2]</td>
                            <td>@Model.Rows[i][3]</td>
                            <td>@Model.Rows[i][4]</td>
                            <td>@Model.Rows[i][5]</td>
                            <td>@Model.Rows[i][6]</td>
                            <td>@Model.Rows[i][7]</td>
                            <td>@Model.Rows[i][8]</td>
                            <td>@Model.Rows[i][9]</td>
                            <td>@Model.Rows[i][10]</td>
                            <td>@Model.Rows[i][11]</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="@Url.Action("StoreAddResistors", "Store",new {@id=@Model.Rows[i][0] } )">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                     }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Is there any way to reduce the loading time of the webpage?

Comment: Yes - don't return so much data.

Comment: @IanKemp If it is possible i won't ask this here :)

Comment: The only thing that's impossible is your willingness to make the changes required to make the page not load slowly. You want a simple solution to a complex problem and you aren't going to get it.

Comment: @IanKemp If I'm searching a simple solution I definitely will reduce the number of returning data. But I am searching real answer for this situation.

Comment: use a paginated view

Answer (score 0):

try to split the page into several. Or is it possible to somehow connect several html documents to 1 page? I have no more idea